# populate jsTree from Sharepoint list

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, jstree

trying to populate js tree from sharepoint list using sample code from official site. I'm new to JS and REST. Please advice what's wrong with the code, 'cause I'm getting "underfined" in alert window and empty tree

```
<div id="ajaxtree"></div>
<script>
    $('#ajaxtree').jstree({
        'core': {
            'data': {
                'url': "http://SPSITE/sites/tree/_api/lists/getbytitle('deps')/items",
                'data': function (node) {
                    alert(node.Title);
                    return { 'id': node.id };
                }
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: you can inspect the network traffic and response data using chrome inspector, or a quick & dirty way, put `http://SPSITE/sites/tree/_api/lists/getbytitle('deps')/items` in your browser and update the response in your question

Comment: found out that sharepoint returns data in XML format while jsTree needs in in JSON. Is it possible to set data format in a REST request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need data in JSON you can use jQuery $.getJSON() or you can modify your request content type and headers on your request. To modify a $.ajax request, use the following:

```
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        method: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json",
        headers: {
            accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
        }
    });
```

I'm actually not sure how to do this within the jstree API (so that just using the URL works like their examples), but I do know you can just retrieve the JSON data and pass it in to the jstree constructor as the value for the 'data' key

Comment: I've changed the code to following:
<code>$('#tree').jstree({
        'core': {
            'data': {
                'url': "http://SPSITE/sites/tree/Shared%20Documents/dull.txt",
                type: "GET",
                headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose", },
                'data': function (node) {
                    return { 'id': node.id };
                }
            }
        }
        });
</code>

Comment: dull.txt files contains data from jsTree sample:
{ "id" : "ajson1", "parent" : "#", "text" : "Simple root node" },
       { "id" : "ajson2", "parent" : "#", "text" : "Root node 2" },
       { "id" : "ajson3", "parent" : "ajson2", "text" : "Child 1" },
       { "id" : "ajson4", "parent" : "ajson2", "text" : "Child 2" }

Now I can see that the same data returns in request body, but the tree stays empty...